# php preg_match() regular expression

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I am working on SEO thing in project to match best URL from possible url's, so 
i am trying to match request url using `preg_match()` function from url pattern

can anyone please help me create regular expression to match only specific urls from all urls, i am newbie in Regular expression, please see my stuff

following **6** urls,

> 1) http://domain.com/pressrelease 
>   2) http://domain.com/pressrelease/ 
>   3) http://domain.com/pressrelease/index/1 
>   4) http://domain.com/pressrelease/index/1/1/1 
>   5) http://domain.com/pressrelease/inde2x/ 
>   6) http://domain.com/pressrelease/inde2x/2

i want to match `1,2,3` urls, other 3 invalid

i create this regular expression but it's does not working

```
(\/pressrelease\/)+((?!index).)*$
```

Comment: Could you explain why 4) 5) 6) are invalid? what is/are the rule(s)?

Comment: i want to match best url's, so take the best urls of tie that wont matter a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex might work for you:

```
(/pressrelease)(/index/\d+)?/?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zT9xU3/1)

Comment: Sorry to say it, but this would go though: http://domain.com/pressrelease/index/1151523

Comment: I didn't get that comment. Why should it not allow `domain.com/pressrelease/index/1151523`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see all the point of your request.

(@^http[s]?://[^/]*/[^/]*?(/?(index/[^/])?)?$@)

This will resolve your 1,2,3 but not the 4,5,6

https://regex101.com/r/fQ0hZ8/2

Comment: no need to match domain and host, anyway working fine

Answer (score 1):

This is 100% working:

```
/(\/pressrelease)(\/)?((index))?(\/1)?$/m
```

https://regex101.com/r/kD9uD9/1

Here isn't a way to cheat around it

Comment: minor modify `/(/pressrelease)(/)?((index))?(/\d+)?$/m` other then fine

Comment: Was just working from your URL, you didn't say what you expected to be chaned yet still working.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to capture the whole string

```
(http:\/\/.*pressrelease(()|(\/)|(\/index)|(\/index\/[^\/]*)))$
```

https://regex101.com/r/aI0fB1/1